# Strange things when running python code in Clion

Tags: python, clion

When running python code in Clion, the output in 'Run' windows has extra content. For example:

```
print("hello")
print("hello")
print("hello")
```

And the output is like this:

```
D:\Anaconda\python.exe G:/code/CProject/test/pyt.py
hello]0;D:\Anaconda\python.exe
hello
hello

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Why there is an extra statement behind the first print()? One feasible solution is "Run with python Console, but for my computer it is too slow. Maybe any better solution?

My python interpreter is 3.9 in Anaconda. By the way, when use input() function, it will repeat my input.

Answer (score 2):

After that, I found a possible solution. Choose "Emulate terminal in output console" in Running\Debug Configurations. For some reason, maybe it is not showed. You can change to another interpreter and choose it, then change back it.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aosOl.png)